# Is there a way track where/when a given Docker image in my registry has been run?

Tags: docker

If I want to know where and when a Docker image in my container registry has been run (e.g., for audit purposes, to see what images are being used the most, or to see if an image is truly stale before deleting it), what are the best tools for getting that information?

(For example, for a VM analogy on AWS: I could check the log of API calls via AWS CloudTrail for when EC2 instances have started and stopped, get the instance IDs, and then join that against the VM image that was running on those images.)

Answer (score 3):

Docker images are downloaded from registry onto hosts, so you would not know if someone starts an image pulled from the registry: it is already downloaded.

There is in fact no way for you to know that an image has started on a host, except if you implement a proper reporting on bootstrap/entrypoint.

Cluster orchestrators can of course provide you adequate reporting on when are started pods/containers, but you should refer to the respective documentation for this.

Answer (score 3):

You could attach to each docker daemon to listen to its Events:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/events/

Also you can filter them by any criteria.

Docker images report the following events:

```
delete
import
load
pull
push
save
tag
untag
```